# Get the index of some JCheckBox's

Tags: java, swing, jcheckbox

I have researched already but yet haven't gotten further in this code.
I am building a GUI pizza calculator that sums the size and crust (radio buttons) with how many toppings are selected (check boxes) and retrieve the final value.

I created the check boxes array and for loop:

```
        String[] toppings = {"Chicken", "Sausage", "Schrimp", "Mushroom", "Green pepper", "Tomatoe", "Onion", "Spinach", "Cheddar", "Mozzarela"};
            JCheckBox[] checkBoxes1 = new JCheckBox[toppings.length];
            for (int i = 0; i < checkBoxes1.length; i++) {
                checkBoxes1[i] = new JCheckBox(toppings[i]);
                checkBoxes1[i].setActionCommand(toppings[i]);
                p4.add(checkBoxes1[i]);
            }
```

-P4 is the panel where the check boxes are located-

Then I have another function to return that value and pop up with JOption the total value.

```
public void finalPrice(){

    double sizeP = 0;
    double crustP = 0;
    double topP = 0;
    double totalP = 0;

    ButtonModel model1 = bg1.getSelection();
    String selec1 = (model1 == null) ? "" : model1.getActionCommand();
    ButtonModel model2 = bg2.getSelection();
    String selec2 = (model2 == null) ? "" : model2.getActionCommand();
    System.out.println(selec1 + " " + selec2);

    switch (selec1) {
    case "Small":
        sizeP = 4.50;
        break;
    case "Medium":
        sizeP = 7;
        break;
    case "Large":
        sizeP = 9;
        break;
    }

    switch (selec2) {
    case "Crunchy Thin Crust":
        crustP = 1;
        break;
    case "Hand Tossed Thin":
        crustP = 1.5;
        break;
    case "Medium Crust":
        crustP = 1.75;
        break;
    case "Homemade Pan":
        crustP = 2;
        break;
    }


    totalP = sizeP + crustP + topP;

    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, 
            "Pizza Size: $" + sizeP +
            "\nPizza Crust: $" + crustP +
            "\nPizza Toppings: $" + topP +
            "\nTotal Price: $" + totalP
            );

}
```

I've tried to use JLists and then get the index, but it was unsuccessful.

Runnable example:

http://collabedit.com/bq2nj

Any ideas?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Consider providing a [runnable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem

Comment: As an "idea" - Instead of waiting till the end to try and pull all the information together, devise some kind of model, which maintains the information you need, so when you select a checkbox, it adds the "topping", when you deselect a checkbox, it removes it.  Items should be maintained in some kind of "plain old java object" (POJO) containing both the description and the cost

Comment: *"This is the unable example:"* ... not according to [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) it isn't

Comment: *"This is the unable example:"* A runnable example is code in text form. That text must be posted here, as an [edit] to the question. In this case, a screenshot of the GUI does not provide much, if any, useful information.

Answer (score 0):

For those who have the same problem as I do, I did it creating a simple for loop

```
        index = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < checkBoxes1.length; i++) {
        if(checkBoxes1[i].isSelected()){
            index += 1;
        }
    }
```

Thank you for your help @MadProgrammer